# Create HashMap from HashSet value using loop

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, hashset

I'm trying to create a HashMap from values of a HashSet (which itself is stored as values in a HashMap).

I'm not sure whether to Iterate or use a for loop.

Example:

```
newMap = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
HashSet<String> boxing = new HashSet<String>();
        
        newMap.put("fighting", boxing);
        boxing.add("jab");
        boxing.add("hook");
        boxing.add("uppercut");
```

Now I need to iterate or loop through so that each value in the 'boxing' HashSet creates a new HashMap with the value as the key for the new map.

So newMap1 would have 'jab' as the key, newMap2 would have 'hook' as the key and so on.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you trying to solve?

Comment: Are you trying to create the "backwards" mapping?  You've said what the keys should be, what should the corresponding values be?

Comment: “So newMap1 would have 'jab' as the key, newMap2 would have 'hook' as the key and so on.”  And what are the corresponding values in each of those Maps?

Comment: @VGR That's right. The values in those maps would be a HashSet, which would be created from the rest of the values in the original. So newMap1 would have 'jab' as the key, and a HashSet with values hook, uppercut.

Comment: So, you want each of the new Maps to have values consisting of all values in `boxing` other than the value used as the new Map’s key?

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 9 you can do this:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> newMap = Map.of("fighting", Set.of("jab","hook","uppercut"));
```

Comment: This is correct, but it doesn’t answer this part of the question: “So newMap1 would have 'jab' as the key, newMap2 would have 'hook' as the key and so on.”